# Restrict windows authentication to access a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server is operating in mixed mode, and I am accessing all my databases with Windows authentication, but I want to restrict one of my database to be accessed by Windows authentication and it should be accessed by SQL Server login user.

I have created a new user and then assign him the rights to access database 
from security tab. But this database is also accessible from Windows authentication.

Comment: Users, regardless of Windows or SQL authentication, can only access a database if they are granted access. If a Windows login can access the database, they have been granted access or are a member of the sysadmin server role.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to DB properties and then flag the security options in the authorization tab.

So, first of all, right click on db name and go to properties. It will pop-up another window with the authorizations tab. Here you can select every single user and decide to grant or not access/modifying ecc...